# current location is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, geomap

The following code display my wrong current location please help me what is wrong with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly, what happens with your code and is this your full code? Please answer these questions and we'll try to help

Comment: No this is not full code actually i dont know how to get the current location from google map and i want help

Comment: If you get a location and it's wrong either you, as the client, are providing the API bad information or you could be swapping longitude and latitude, which I do on occasion at work lol

Comment: I don't understand, it's as easy as this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NGja4/177/)

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is correct.

I've experienced cases where it returns the wrong location on 2 of my friend's laptops using Safari and Chrome. We were a location A while the JavaScript geolocation was displaying the home address of one friend, and for the other friend it displayed some random location which he had visited weeks prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple please follow this procedure

**Time settings:**

- Settings > Storage > Cached data > Clear cached data
- Settings > Date & Time
- Switch between time zones
- Select automatic time and date

**Power settings:**

- Settings > Power Manager > Disable power saving mode
- Settings > Scroll down to location.
- Select High accuracy mode.

**Storage settings:**

- Go to settings > Storage > Apps/Application Manager > All > Google Play Services > Clear data
- Go to Settings > Storage > Apps/Application Manager > All > Google Maps > Force stop and Clear data

**Restart:**

- Restart device.
- Open Google maps menu settings
- Sign out and sign back in to Google maps.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?co=GENIE.Platform=Android&hl=en&oco=1